# PyInstaller app keeps opening itself while using pyQode

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Problem: The following program is keep starting itself every 5 seconds after making it executable using PyInstaller. It keeps running itself again and again. The code works fine without making if I run it directly using python.
I spent more than a day to fix this issue but no luck so far.
I tried it on Windows and Mac. Python version 3.7, PyInstaller Version 3.5 & 3.6.

PyInstaller Command:

```terminal
pyinstaller --onefile generic_code_edit.py
```

Python Code:

```python
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
import sys
from pyqode.qt import QtWidgets
from pyqode.core.widgets import GenericCodeEdit


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # create editor and window
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    editor = GenericCodeEdit()

    # open a file
    editor.file.open(__file__)
    window.setCentralWidget(editor)

    # run
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
    editor.file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The Debug log:

> DEBUG:pyqode.core.cache:getting encoding for generic_code_edit.py
>   DEBUG:pyqode.core.managers.file:mimetype detected: text/x-python
>   DEBUG:pyqode.core.managers.file:file open: generic_code_edit.py
>   ERROR:pyqode.backend:DEBUG:pyqode.qt:importing PyQt5
>   ERROR:pyqode.backend:DEBUG:pyqode.qt:imported PyQt5
>   ERROR:pyqode.backend:INFO:pyqode.qt:using pyqt5
>   ERROR:pyqode.backend:DEBUG:pyqode.core.cache:getting encoding for
>   generic_code_edit.py
>   ERROR:pyqode.backend:DEBUG:pyqode.core.managers.file:mimetype
>   detected: text/x-python
>   ERROR:pyqode.backend:DEBUG:pyqode.core.managers.file:file open:
>   generic_code_edit.py

**Update:**

Finally I found the problem. It is related to the autocomplete feature. This feature does not load perfectly with pyinstaller and cause a new start. Although I could not be able to make it working with pyinstaller, but I have been able to stop these feature to solve the starting loop issue.

I have passed an empty server file as backend to solve the issue. But still I want to make the Autocomplete working with pyinstaller.

```python
editor = GenericCodeEdit(None, 'empty_file.py')
```